# Count unique values by group in R

Tags: r

I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
SID     group  timepoint 
 5402       A    0
 5402       B    0
 5402       C    1
 5403       A    0     
25403       B    1
25403       C    1
```

I want to count how many unique SID's are there per group x timepoint. 
So far I have been doing the combinations 'by hand', like this:

```
length(unique(subset(df, timepoint=='0' & group=='A')$SID))
length(unique(subset(df, timepoint=='0' & group=='B')$SID))
...
```

Is there a way to use a grouping function that gives me a table with all the counts? (like `by`, or `tapply`?)
Thanks!

Comment: I wonder, did you try Googling the title of your own question? Just by copy/pasting your title into Google I'm getting so many good search results.

Comment: @DavidArenburg, I did try to search for it! But I think I focused on trying to find out how use tapply or by and forgot to search for the obvious :-(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `uniqueN` from `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1)`), grouped by 'group' and 'timepoint', get the length of `unique` elements of 'SID' (`uniqueN(SID)`).

```
 library(data.table)
 setDT(df1)[, .(UnSID=uniqueN(SID)), .(group, timepoint)]
```

Comment: that worked, thanks!